# Kafka trigger a compaction on low throughput topic

Tags: apache-kafka

A common concern for PII on a compacted topic is to ensure that after some time the topic gets compacted *even though no new message is written* to it and thus triggers a segment close and compaction.

Using kafka 2.6

The topic I have needs to be compacted 1 hour after some PII cleaning is written, and as the topic is very low volume there might not be any more writes for a couple of days. Thus the old and new key/values stays.

When reading: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-354%3A+Add+a+Maximum+Log+Compaction+Lag its not clear wether a write needs to happen or if some house-keeping would ensure closing active segment and then a compaction.

I am configure topic with:

- cleanup.policy=compact
- min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01
- min.compaction.lag.ms=<1 hour>
- max.compaction.lag.ms=<1 hour>
- segment.ms=<1 hour>
- segment.bytes=<1 MB>

What am I missing

Comment: Remove the config for min.compaction.lag.ms so that it defaults to zero. This should allow compaction to occur by creating a new active segment without a write.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but I am afraid it made no difference. Can still observe kafka logs that as soon as I make a write the compaction kicks in, otherwise not

Comment: I would also suggest setting segment.ms to a very short timeframe (for testing perhaps 100ms)

Comment: segment.bytes may also be too large.

Comment: i tried lower those as well, but again it didn't help. Its not clear if there is some house keeping that does this work without a write trigger